# I have a grid with a border around it how do I paint the inside of the grid?

Tags: java, android, grid

Okay I have a game I'm working on that sets a 12x16 grid on the screen and then draws a pattern on the screen like so http://oi49.tinypic.com/53odih.jpg

I'm just wondering if there is a way using code to see if the box exists inside of the pattern or not?

This is how I'm looping though my grid boxes

```
    //Set all blocks to default
    for(int i=0;i<tilesX;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<tilesY;j++){
            blocks[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

If a block is part of a pattern I set the block to 1. I want the blocks inside the pattern set to 2, but I can't think of a way to do this programmatically. The pattern will always be a complete shape and will always connect back to the starting point.

I hope that's not too confusing and I'm willing to provide you with what ever you need but I'm just lost on how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Get a higher accept-rate, maybe you will receive more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the [flood fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).  Depending on how you draw the state of 2, you can flood fill the area starting at a known point inside the shape.  Then check to see if its 0 (outside), 1 (border), or 2 (inside).

I think I'm grasping what you want here, but let me know if I'm off base.

Comment: If it ends up working out you can check my answer as the solution, so other people know its the right one. Thanks and good luck!